# Extend required interface field to another interface, but make all subfields optional

Tags: typescript, interface

I've got 2 interfaces:

```
interface BattleSkills {
  strength: number;
  armor: number;
  magic_resistance: number;
  health: number;
  mana: number;
  intelligence: number;
  accuracy: number;
  agility: number;
  critical_damage: number;
}
```

and

```
interface Item {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  price: number;
  stats: BattleSkills;
}
```

At the moment `Item['stats']` requires all fields from `BattleSkills`. How can I tweak this to keep `stats` field required, but all it's subfields optional? Preferably without making fields within `BattleSkills` optional themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`Partial` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialt) that ships with TypeScript:

```js
interface Item {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  price: number;
  stats: Partial<BattleSkills>;
}
```

`Partial` essentially gives you a copy of the type you pass in, but makes every property optional.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you. Just discovered typescript's utility page, this is gonna help a lot in the future!